# Как правильно написать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Житель Москвы спасен работниками МЧС *при* пожаре или *на* пожаре? Если можно, подробный ответ. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Тут несколько разный смысл получается. "При пожаре" может означать, что где-то происходит пожар, а рядом сотрудник МЧС спасал жителя Москвы. "На пожаре" уже конкретно поясняет, что спасение состаялось на конкретном пожаре.
Хотя, мне кажется, лучше бы прозвучало "спасен из пожара" или "во время пожара".

Answer (score 1):

Подумать надо. Столько всяких вариантов.

Получил травму во время пожара, (имущество) пострадало от пожара, проявил отвагу на пожаре, действия при пожаре. 
Спасение, похоже, всё-таки - **на пожаре**. Как и "спасение на воде". Отдаёт некоторым чиновничьим косноязычием, но выбирать не из чего.

Answer (score 0):

А ещё лучше - спасён из огня во время пожара.